# Installing RSelenium from GitHub

Tags: r, rselenium

I want to use RSelenium for R, but it has been removed from CRAN. I decided to follow the guides using a download/installation from GitHub but I get an error message that I cant explain.

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
```

R Starts downloading

```
Downloading GitHub repo ropensci/RSelenium@master
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                             
2: CRAN packages only              
3: None                            
4: XML (3.98-1.20 -> 3.99-0) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:
```

Im entering 1, because I want everything updated.

```
XML        (3.98-1.20 -> 3.99-0) [CRAN]
wdman      (NA        -> 0.2.4 ) [CRAN]
binman     (NA        -> 0.1.1 ) [CRAN]
subprocess (NA        -> 0.8.3 ) [CRAN]
semver     (NA        -> 0.2.0 ) [CRAN]
Installing 5 packages: XML, wdman, binman, subprocess, semver

Error: Failed to install 'RSelenium' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) unable to access index for repository http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
```

How can I fix that issue? (My version of R and RStudio are updated, thats what usually makes packages not work for me. The problem fixer no1 "Restart R Studio" didn't help either ;) ).

Comment: `RSelenium` apparently suggests an [additional repo](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L23), which is causing R to look at omegahat. That repo does not support macosx, apparently. Try "2", CRAN only, to see if it will skip the additional repo and go with the mainstream urls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still getting the same error message. I tried 1 - 4, the error doesnt change.

Comment: It works for me. But I had all those packages installed already. Try installing them one by one and install `RSelenium` last. My guess is your problem is with one of the other packages.

Comment: As an alternative, `git clone` the repo. From there, you can try (1) `devtools::load_all` (needs to be done every session); (2) `devtools::install` (just once); (3) edit the `DESCRIPTION` file, remove the `Additional_repositories:` line, then try again either #1 or #2. (Once it's installed, you can safely delete the cloned repo directory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that some of the dependecies are not available on your default `repo`. Specifically, this doesn't work:

```
install.packages("binman", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

`RSelenium` is also currently available on `CRAN`. So all you should have to do is to select a `CRAN` mirror which has these packages. For example:

```
install.packages(c("XML", "wdman", "binman", "subprocess", "semver", "RSelenium"), 
                 repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that one worked! 

I tried
`library("RSelenium")`

about 1 hour ago and I got a Cran Error ("Currently not available on CRAN) ... strange